# Creating a copy of a mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb replica set (1 primary, 2 secondary instances): vm1, vm2, vm3.

I had a need for a second replica set so I created a copy of the above vms: vm4, vm5, vm6.

After booting up vms[4-6]  and connecting to them, obviously, when checking the members of the cluster with `rs.status()` , I can still see vm[1-3] listed as members of the cluster there instead of the new vms. My question is:

Can I use `rs.reconfig()` to update at once all the members in the second triad so that I have 2 independent clusters while leaving the data intact? The expected outcome is to have two independent clusters:

- cluster1: vm1, vm2, vm3
- cluster2: vm4, vm5, vm6

that (initially) have the same data and function independently.

Is my approach correct or should I be doing this differently?
Should I just export data from the initial cluster, create a fresh replica set and then import data back to the new cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create empty instances of vm4, vm5, vm6. Start them and add them to your replica set with `rs.add()`. It will trigger an initial sync and after a short time you will have everything properly replicated.

Or do you ask for an independent second replica set of 3 members? In this case, copy data just from one secondary to one of your vm in cluster 2

Connect to the new vm and drop the `local` database. Then you can use `rs.init()` and `rs.add()` again.

Follow this instruction: [Restore a Replica Set from MongoDB Backups](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/)

Comment: Hi Wernfried, sorry if my question was unclear, I was indeed referring to the second case(independent replica). I followed your instructions and everything worked like a charm. Thank you.